# Magnificent Mansion in another Magnificent Mansion

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Okay so serious question, I had to stop a session short because my players were arguing. what would happen if you use Magnificent Mansion while already in a Magnificent Mansion. My players argued it would make a black hole, others argued nothing would happen.

Comment: While the linked question answers this correctly, I would seriously look at your lack of authority in this group if it brought a session to a halt.

Comment: Well I had to stop the session because no one agreed on what would happen. If I ruled it one way or the other I would have a group of players upset about the outcome. Also the session was 40 minutes away from being over anyways